# RegEx not finding all matches

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I have the following code (AS3 & CS 5.5):

```
var regEx:RegExp = new RegExp(/(?:^|\s)(\#[^\s$]+)/g);
var txt:String = "This #asd is a test tweet #hash1 test #hash2 test";

var matches:Object = regEx.exec(txt);
trace(matches);
```

The trace returns '#asd,#asd'. I really don't understand why it would to this, as in my RegEx testing application 'RegExhibit' it returns '#asd,#hash1,#hash2', which is what I'd expect. Can anyone shed any light on this please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using `.exec`, you should run it multiple times to get all results:

> In the following example, the g (global) flag is set in the regular expression, so you can use exec() repeatedly to find multiple matches:

```
var myPattern:RegExp = /(\w*)sh(\w*)/ig;  
var str:String = "She sells seashells by the seashore";
var result:Object = myPattern.exec(str);

while (result != null) {
    trace (result.index, "\t", result);
    result = myPattern.exec(str);
}
```

Source: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/RegExp.html

A better alternative is probably to use [`String.match`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#match%28%29):

> If pattern is a regular expression, in order to return an array with more than one matching substring, the g (global) flag must be set in the regular expression

An example should be (not tested):

```
var regEx:RegExp = /(?:^|\s)(\#[^\s$]+)/g;
var txt:String = "This #asd is a test tweet #hash1 test #hash2 test";

var matches:Object = txt.match(regEx);
```